# Using acrylic paint lettering

Tags: finishing, wood, design, sanding

Good morning.
I am making a charcuterie board and want to use water based acrylic for decorative lettering. All of the sanding has been done. Should I use the mineral oil coating prior to putting on the acrylic or vice versa?
Thank You!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SE. There are a couple of things here, including stuff not related to your query. The first is should you use acrylic for lettering in the first place? Now "acrylic paint" spans a whole range of surprisingly different things, but if you're planning on using what I think you are I can tell you that there's every chance that the lettering won't last anything like as long as you hope it will if the board is intended to be functional and not decorative. So how long *are* you hoping this will last? :-)

Comment: The second thing I want to highlight is the the embodied assumption that the mineral oil is somehow mandatory — there's no rule that says you have to oil a board, and if you do whether whether this oil is the thing to do it with.

Answer (score 2):

You should absolutely not apply mineral oil prior to painting.  It will almost certainly interfere with the paint adhering and/or curing.